# Properties of Integral Closure

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra

> **Definition(Integral closure)**: Let $R$ be a ring and $I$ an ideal of $R$. An element $x$ is said to be integral over $I$ if $x$ satisﬁes a monic equation
>   $x^n + i_1x^{n−1} + ··· + i_n = 0$ such that $i_j ∈ I^j$ .

Let $ R $ be a ring and $ I $ ideals of $ R $  and $ I $  be a finitely generated.

**Questions:**

1. The integral closure of $ \text{rad}(I) $ is equal to the radical of the integral closure of $ I $.
2. The integral closure of a homogeneous ideal is homogeneous.

Comment: Your questions mention neither reduction nor the ideal $J$, is this normal? (no pun intended).

Comment: Is this homework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) is obvious : a radical ideal is integrally closed, so $I\subset \mathrm{rad}(I)$ gives $\bar{I}\subset \mathrm{rad}(I)$, hence $\mathrm{rad}(\bar{I})=\mathrm{rad}(I)$.

2) is more subtle. This is Corollary 5.2.3 in "Integral Closure of Ideals, Rings, and Modules" by Swanson and Huneke, London Mathematical Society Lecture Note Series 336. I recommend that you look at that book for further questions about integral closure (it is available on the web).